How to configure Cube.js pre-aggregations to refresh every 12 hours or at a specific time (e.g., 4:00 AM UTC)?
I’m working on a Cube.js project where I need to configure pre-aggregations to refresh at regular intervals, specifically every 12 hours or at a specific time like 4:00 AM UTC. I’ve set up a cube to optimize query performance using pre-aggregations, but I'm unsure how to configure the refresh schedule to achieve this behavior.
When testing the last refresh using Postman, for example, checking every 5 minutes, Cube.js doesn’t seem to respect the scheduled refresh time, even though I’ve set it for every 5 minutes. The refresh happens inconsistently.
Here’s an example of my Orders cube where I want to apply these configurations:
cube('Orders', {
  sql: `SELECT id, user_id, total_price, added_at FROM public.orders`,

  preAggregations: {
    OrdersSummary: {
      dimensions: [Orders.id, Orders.userId, Orders.totalPrice],
      refreshKey: {
        every: '12 hour'
      }
    },
    OrdersDetails: {
      dimensions: [Orders.id, Orders.userId, Orders.addedAt],
      refreshKey: {
        every: '12 hour'
      }
    }
  },

  dimensions: {
    id: {
      sql: `id`,
      type: `number`,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    userId: {
      sql: `user_id`,
      type: `number`
    },
    totalPrice: {
      sql: `total_price`,
      type: `number`
    },
    addedAt: {
      sql: `added_at`,
      type: `time`
    }
  }
});


Have you tried it with cron? Like this:
refresh_key: {
  every: "0 13  * * *", 
  timezone: "Europe/Amsterdam",
  }

This refreshes the preaggregation everyday at 13.00h Amsterdam time.
This you can use to run at 01.00 and 13.00
0 1,13 * * *

https://cube.dev/docs/reference/data-model/cube#refresh_key
https://crontab.guru

Yes, but it doesn't respect the scheduled timing for automatic refreshes. It always requires a manual trigger through the web UI to refresh, and even then, it takes between 5 to 20 minutes to get the data.
